# Generic geometry node graph to extrude mesh?

Tags: extrude, geometry-nodes

Has anyone managed to make a generic "extrude" mesh surface operation in geometry nodes?

I want to do the equivalent of taking a flat grid, extruding it up 1000 units, and down 1000 units; such that Im left with three copies of the surface connected by faces.

The closes I've come is this; which works but isn't generic.  This generates a mesh from curve (using a line profile), then makes a cube and rearranges the faces to fit.

[image]

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

With the node `Extrude` *(Blender 3.1+)* you should be able to get - after I rebuilt your nodes - exactly what you are looking for.

If you use the node twice in a row, and only use the selection *Top* from the first node for the second, your grid will first be extruded from 2D to a 3D mesh, and then only the top faces.

[image]